# how to change view controller on swipe in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I want to change view controllers by swiping controller like i when i swipe the message box should swipe from ViewController1->ViewController2 and from viewController1<-viewController2 i know i have to use `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` or may be `UIScrollView` or `UIPageController` with contents of ViewControllers not Views. like default messageViewController swipe to EmailViewController or EmailViewController to MessageViewController. is there any idea how to do like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)goToNext{
    //your code to load youn next view controller
}

- (void)goToBack{
    //your code to load your previous view controller
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer;

    recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(goToNext)];
    [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [recognizer release];

    recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(goToBack)];
    [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [recognizer release];
}
```

Comment: thank you. i know this but this will change the view controller like changing the pages in iphone.

Comment: and what exactly you want to do?

Comment: plz download `mobli` app and check in that they are changing viewControllers by swiping Feed->Me->Popular->etc... i want to do some thing like this but i want to change the views of iPhone Message->Email MessageController by swiping.

Comment: nad what kind of swiping do you need? there is just "swipe" and go

Comment: swiping just like changing page. and open the emailcomposer or messagecomposer like you can find in iPad by swiping. with your 4 fingers on screen while app is opened more than 2